# How to use <sw-media-field> component?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am trying to get the id of uploaded image file via sw-media-field.
https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-media-field

`<sw-media-field label="Profile Pic" :mediaId="user.mediaId"></sw-media-field>`

Is this correct implmentation?

Is the methods considered as vue js events? How to implement them in shopware? Do i have to override **@media-upload-finish** in sw-media-field twig block or something

Also even though file is upload, no preview of the uploaded picture is visible?

```
<sw-media-field label="Profile Pic" :mediaId="user.mediaId">
<template v-slot:sw_media_field_upload_component>
<sw-upload-listener
:uploadTag="uploadTag"
autoUpload
@media-upload-finish="customAction">
</sw-upload-listener>
<sw-media-upload-v2
v-if="showUploadField"
variant="regular"
:allowMultiSelect="false"
:uploadTag="uploadTag">
</sw-media-upload-v2>
</template>
</sw-media-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an event `media-id-change` you can listen to. You may also use the `v-model` bind instead of the `mediaId` property to simplify if all you need the listener for is to set the id.

```html
<sw-media-field
    :media-id="mediaId"
    label="Profile Pic"
    @media-id-change="onMediaIdChange"
/>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        mediaId: null,
    };
},

methods: {
    onMediaIdChange(value) {
        this.mediaId = value;
    },
},
```

or simply

```html
<sw-media-field
    v-model="mediaId"
    label="Profile Pic"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to remove the media-listing in sw-media-field. Is it possible to override the sw-media-field twig using component.override function only for certain route.